# How to get a large space each 3 columns with ng-repeat/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to break my ng-repeat with a large space (like 50px) each 3 columns. I am using bootstrap 3. Like the picture bellow, but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any idea what do I have to use ?

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Choose your flight</h2>
            <img src="images/aircraft-entire.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="seat in seats">
      <div class="col-md-1" id="seats"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one :

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="seat in seats">
  <div class="col-md-1 {{$index % 3 === 1 ? 'col-md-offset-2' : ''}}" id="seats"></div>
</div>
```